# Testing Okhttp3 response body - java.lang.IllegalStateException: request == null

Tags: java, mockito, httprequest, httpresponse, okhttp

I have a method in class which does a HTTP GET call to get the response object and utilize this object further. The pesudo code is below:

```
public class ABC{
 public method abc1(){
  HttpUrl url = HttpUrl.parse("url").newBuilder()
    .addPathSegment("path1")
    .build();

  Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
  try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
   ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
   String body = responseBody.string();
   //other logic
  }catch (IOException e) {}

 }
}
```

Now I am writing a unit test to test with different values in the response object (json object). This is as below:

```
public class ABCTest{
 @Mock
 private OkHttpClient mockHttpClient;
 @Mock
 private Call mockCall;

 @Before
 public void initMocks() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
 }

 @Test
 public void abc1Test(){

  ResponseObjectInJson responseObjectInJson = new ResponseObjectInJson(); //this is a object from my POJO class that i create in order to be received as a response

  JSONObject jsonObject = new 
  JSONObject(responseObjectInJson);

  ResponseBody body = 
  ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"),new 
  Gson().toJson(jsonObject));

  Response.Builder builder = new Response.Builder();
  builder.code(200);
  Response response = builder.body(body).build();

  when(mockCall.execute()).thenReturn(response);
  when(mockHttpClient.newCall(any(Request.class))).thenReturn(mockCall);
  //call the abc1() method here to see the response and behaviour
 }
}
```

The problem is, when i debug, it throws InvocationTargetException when building the response builder.body(body).build();

And shows java.lang.IllegalStateException: request == null. I understand that i need to set request in the Response.Builder because when i evaluate the expression builder.body(body) in debugger, in the result it shows headers and body, but request is null.

```
i.e., builder.request(//a request here)
```

My question is:
1. In response why the request is needed?
2. How to set this? because i am unable to mock since its final.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any luck? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @Harish yes. when building the response to be returned when mockCall is executed.,I had to set the request in the response and also headers and other attributes that shows error. Then it works. I did not get the reason, but by doing so it worked.

Comment: @Harish if my above comment was useful, could you please upvote my comment